# Config statement cannot be used inside a user transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm currently getting the following error when trying to run the RECONFIGURE statement inside a Transaction : -

> CONFIG statement cannot be used inside a user transaction.

Is there anyway of running this command asynchronously or any other way that would fix the error?

This is a simplified version of what I'm doing that will reproduce the error:-

```
BEGIN Transaction

EXEC sp_configure 'clr enabled', 1

RECONFIGURE

Commit Transaction
```

Comment: Why are you trying to execute RECONFIGURE inside a transaction? You can't roll it back.

Comment: What is the reason of doing reconfigure in transaction? Sounds for me like [XY-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: When we do a build we have a script to build the database. I need to enable CLR and I understand that once this command has been executed you need to run RECONFIGURE to make it work

Comment: @Shazoo ok, but why should it be done in transaction? Enabling clr is mostly one-time action, there is no need to swich it on and off all the time.

Comment: Because the script to build the database gets deployed on many servers. It would be a pain to have to go and do it manually on each one even though it only needs to be done once. I thought there might be a way to do it within the script.

Comment: @Shazoo, you're not understanding what the commenters are really asking.   Why does this need a transaction?   Why can't you just remove the `BEGIN Transaction` and `Commit Transaction` lines from your script?   What does having a transaction get you?

Comment: @Shazoo Well, creating database using script is not something uncommon. But I still don't understand why do you need to create/configure these bases in transaction. I see no benefits of transaction in this case.

Comment: The transaction is something that is added by our DB configurator when it runs the scripts. I don't have any control over this unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

From [Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191544(v=sql.105).aspx):

You can use all Transact-SQL statements in an explicit transaction, except for the following statements:

[image]

**You also cannot use the following:**

```
Full-text system stored procedures in an explicit transaction.    

sp_dboption to set database options or use any system procedures that modify the master database inside explicit or implicit transactions.     

UPDATE STATISTICS can be used inside an explicit transaction. However, UPDATE STATISTICS commits independently of the enclosing transaction and cannot be rolled back.
```

Answer (score 0):

Transactions are constructs so that you can rollback (undo) what you did, like inserts, updates, etc.  Reconfiguring the server is not something a transaction can rollback.  This is why it isn't allowed within a transaction.  Since the transaction doesn't get you anything here, just remove it from your script.